# can't remove specific event handlers when attached to document with .on()

Tags: event-handling, jquery, jquery-on

Here's a simple fiddle to demo my situation...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/EM6mR/17/

What I'm doing is adding an event handler for current & future elements, using `.on()`. I want to be able to remove these event handlers for specific elements when something happens; in the case of the fiddle, when the radio button is selected, the event handler for the blue elements should be removed and clicking those elements should not do anything anymore.

It doesn't seem to be working :(

How do I remove the event handler attached to `document` that I created with `.on()` for those specific blue elements?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: Was'nt `die()` removed? It's at least deprecated!

Comment: `.die()` is deprecated. `.off()` is the new `.die()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature for your `.on()` and `.off()` has to match.

These two do not match so the `.off()` call won't find matching event handlers to remove:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    update();
});

$(document).off('click', '.blue');
```

Note, the selector passed to `.on()` and `.off()` is different.

---

When using the dynamic form of `.on()` (where you pass a selector as an argument to .on()), you can't remove just part of the items.   That's because there's only one event handler installed on the root element and jQuery can only remove the entire thing or not at all.  So, you can't just `.off()` some of the dynamic items.

Your options are to remove all the event handlers with:

```
$(document).off('click', '.btn');
```

and, then install a new event handler that excludes the items you don't want such as:

```
$(document).off('click', '.btn:not(.blue)');
```

Or, teach the event handler itself how to ignore `.blue` items:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('blue')) {
        update();
    }
});
```

Comment: well, how do I do `.off()` just on the blue elements?

Comment: You'd have to either remove all the original event handlers and set a new event handler that doesn't include the `.blue` items or you'd have to add logic to the event handler to skip any processing of `.blue` items.  You can't just `.off()` some items from a previous dynamic event handler.

Comment: ugh :( ok... thanks for that explanation. please include it as a part of your answer?

Comment: @Hristo - additional info added to my answer.

Comment: Was driving me crazy getting `.off()` to work...I'm sure somewhere someone said the signatures had to match, but I never saw it. Thank you for this!!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of how you attach your events; this works fine for me:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    update();
});

$('#disable').on('change', function() {
        $('.btn').off('click');
});
```

Comment: but this doesn't cover my scenario. doing `$('.btn').on('click', function() {...})` will not work for future `.btn` elements

Answer (score 1):

Only way seems to be:

```
$('#disable').on('change', function() {

        $(document)
           .off('click', '.btn')
           .on('click', '.btn:not(.blue)', update);
    });
```

Comment: this seems so inefficient though... removing all event handlers, and then adding them all back on while ignoring the blue ones...