# Can you target a subsection of elements tagged with .on() with .off()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble with the following scenario:

```
$(document).on("click", ".element", function () {do something}

<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element" attribute="different"></div> //do something different
<div class="element"></div>

$('.element[attribute="different"]').off();
$(document).on("click", ".element[attribute="different", 
  function () {do something unique}
```

In this scenario, the .off() isn't working. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here?

{{Note}}

I cannot modify the original .on event in this case. It's built into the system we're working on to handle specific events.

http://jsfiddle.net/KMrVY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KMrVY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify the original event then it should be possible to install your own delegated click handler at some intermediate point of the document and filter invocations by preventing event propagation:

```
<div id="whatever">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element" attribute="different"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

$(document).on("click", ".element", function () { alert("I 'm untouchable");});

$("#whatever").on("click", ".element", function (event) {
    if ($(this).is("[attribute='different']")) {
        // do something else
        alert("Stop right there!");
        // and stop event propagation
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/xmM57/)**.

Your own markup will probably not have a `div#whatever`, but since you can freely attach the handler anywhere below the document body as long as it's an ancestor of the elements you are targeting, there should be no shortage of alternatives.

Comment: Brilliant. Works like a charm.

Comment: In case you're interested, Jon, I found an alternative. Not sure which method is more elegant, though...

Comment: @voithos: Unfortunately I have already upvoted you. ;-) I wouldn't prefer that method, but it's legit and in some cases (when not using delegated events) there's nothing better.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks! :D Actually I just wanted to alert you in case you were curious, since the method that you found was interesting for me.

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `on` on the relevant attributes to begin with. With this, you don't need to use `off`. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdXcv/) showing precisely how to use this thing.

```
$(document).on('click', '.element[attribute!="different"]', function() {});
```

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15887854/716118) gives some insight on what's going on. Here's an excerpt:

> When using the dynamic form of .on() (where you pass a selector as an
>   argument to .on()), you can't remove just part of the items. That's
>   because there's only one event handler installed on the root element
>   and jQuery can only remove the entire thing or not at all. So, you
>   can't just .off() some of the dynamic items.

A method that he suggests is to `off` the entire event (in your case, on all `.element`s), and then re-create it using the specific selector you need. I've [updated the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KMrVY/1/) to show this in action (although getting the handler function, which you need, isn't pretty).

If you have a reference to the original handler function, it would make it a lot easier.

Comment: That doesn't remove the original event, they both fire now it seems

Comment: @Wesley: It's meant to replace the original event.

Comment: Doesn't seem to do that, I just gave it a shot. They're both firing.

Comment: @Wesley it is meant to replace the _code_ for the original event.

Comment: @Wesley: I added a JSFiddle. (Uses console.log, so open up the console )

Comment: @voithos I see what you mean now. The issue is, I can't modify the original event. I added that to the question to clarify.

Comment: @Wesley: Updated my answer with some more information (different from Jon's)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would have iterated through them if I knew one or more would be different.

Perhaps this isn't as efficient for only a couple elements but it would allow you opt elements out of a .bind()/.on() if you had a lot of them or different ones.

It may be overkill for what you want in this case.

```
$('.element').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('attribute') === 'whatever') {
        $(this).on('click', function() {/*Do something here*/});
    } else {
        $(this).on('click', function() {/*Do something else for all the others*/});
    }
});
```